# what do i need to backup and restore when reinstalling Team foundation server?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I have `Team Foundation Server 2010 trial version`, me and my coworkers have been using it for a while but, now we need to uninstall it in order to reinstall a licensed version, of course i don't need to lose the projects on team foundation server, `how can i backup those projects so that i restore them when i install the licensed version?` what about the database? i need details please.
Thanks in advance

Comment: TFS 2010 is unsupported, it's in your best interest to upgrade to a new version as soon as possible or migrate to Visual Studio Online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dylan is correct that you only need to add a license key rather than doing a re-install.

If possible, I'd encourage you to go with a more recent version of TFS rather than starting with 2010 when 2015 has just been released. Backup/Restore is nicely built in to later versions too.

For TFS 2010 backup you need to manually backup a number of databases.

The critical ones are:
 - TFS_Configuration
 - TFS_Collection(s)

If you're using reporting (although they can be recreated later)
 - TFS_Analysis
 - TFS_Warehouse
 - ReportServer
 - ReportServerTempDB

And if you have any content in SharePoint
 - WSS_Config
 - WSS_Content
 - WSS_AdminContent

[Backup TFS 2010 Manually](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253070(v=vs.100).aspx)

If the server is in use then the backups should be timestamped which is a more involved process (see article above) so in that case it's going to be a lot easier to grab the TFS Power Tools which include a backup tool.

[Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f/)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to uninstall/reinstall.  Just open the admin console and enter a product key to go from Trial Edition to Full.  See here for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc668758.aspx

Comment: thank you but still i need to know what/how to backup and restore projects on tfs